# Stata: Convert String to Date

Tags: database, string, statistics, stata

I am relatively new to Stata. I have a string variable `time` that records year and month in the following format:

```
2000m1
2000m2
2000m3
...
2015m12
```

I would first like to create a date variable that looks identical (but it has to be in the date format) to the above. Second, I would like to separate year and month components into two different variables, and third, I would like to rename the month component to January, February, etc.

For the first task, the command `date = date(time, "YM")` returns an empty variable and I can't figure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's cited here as a command is not a complete command: presumably a starting  `generate` is intended.

Comment: At a guess, because downvoters didn't explain, the downvoting reflects judgments on apparent failure to read the documentation, fairly or otherwise. (SO is not billed as a forum for beginners, but for professional and enthusiast programmers, so reading the documentation is a minimal requirement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `date()` yields **daily dates**, not monthly dates or any other kind of date that isn't a daily date. See its help (`help date()`) which begins

```
date(s1,s2[,Y])
       Description:  the e_d date (days since 01jan1960) corresponding to s1
                     based on s2 and Y

                     s1 contains the date, recorded as a string, in virtually
                     any format.  Months can be spelled out, abbreviated (to
                     three characters), or indicated as numbers; years can
                     include or exclude the century; blanks and punctuation are
                     allowed.

                     s2 is any permutation of M, D, and [##]Y, with their order
                     defining the order that month, day, and year occur in s1.
                     ##, if specified, indicates the default century for
                     two-digit years in s1.  For instance, s2="MD19Y" would
                     translate s1="11/15/91" as 15nov1991.
```

In essence, it needs to be told a day, month and year. You supplied a month and year, and `date()` won't (can't) play.

As documented at the same place, `daily()` is a synonym for the same function and it's good practice to use it to remind yourself (and readers of your code) of what it does.

Correspondingly, `monthly()` provides an easier solution to create a monthly date from string input than in your own answer. Try out solutions using `display` (`di` is allowed) on simple cases where you know the right answer.

```
. di monthly("2000m1", "YM")
480

. di %tm monthly("2000m1", "YM")
 2000m1
```

Reading the documentation is crucial here. See `help datetime` for a start. There is a lot to explain as dates come in many different forms, but it's all documented.

See also `help datetime_display_formats` for how to display dates differently. (No "renaming" is involved here.) For example,

```
. di %tmMonth_CCYY monthly("2000m1", "YM")
  January 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the first part. I post the answer to here for anybody who needs a reference:

```
gen date = ym(real(substr(time, 1,4)),real(substr(time,6,2)))

format date %tm
```

Comment: I reversed the downvote here. This is not in my view the best answer (using `monthly()` is much simpler) but it is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be it works for you

```
string Date1 = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["date"]);
        string Date2 = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["date1"]);

        Date1 = DateTime.Parse(Date1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date2 = DateTime.Parse(Date2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thank you, but "command string is unrecognized" is the error I get when I type the first command.

Comment: Replace this string with your string name

Comment: This isn't Stata syntax. It may or may not be a good alternative for the OP or anybody else, but explaining what language is being used is essential.

Comment: This also appears to produce string output for daily dates, so it is not what is desired even in its own language. The problem is to take monthly date strings and produce numeric equivalents. This answer doesn't overlap with the question at all except in so far as both concern dates.